# answers to my global variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

I am a beginner coder and I have this game I am making, but my problem is that in my game the user has points that they can spend in battle. And it shall update the points variable depending on how much you spend.

```
global Points
    Points = int(100)
def Combat():
    print('how much points would you spend(higher points = higher chance of winning')
    a9 = int(input('>'))
    Points = int(Points)- int(a9)
    global Points
    print('You have ',Points,' points')
```

But for some reason it doesn't change the global point variable, any answers?
Does this have an answer?
Or is it unsolved?

Comment: The answer given is absolutely correct and will fully solve your scope issue! I would recommend researching the Object Oriented Programming side of Python in order to fully understand what makes the language so strong! Classes are a good way to avoid scope issues and greatly reduce re-typing! Good luck, best wishes!

Answer (score 3):

You need the `global Points` to come before you assign it a value within the function, otherwise you are using a `Points` that is local to the function and hides the global Points you want to use:

```
Points = 100

def Combat():
    print('how much points would you spend(higher points = higher chance of winning')
    a9 = int(input('>'))
    global Points
    Points = Points - int(a9)
    print('You have ',Points,' points')
```

Also, your initial use of `global Points` isn't needed, as outside a function is automatically global scope.